# How to install a library with homebrew to use older Xcode SDK on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, homebrew

I use Xcode 7.2 on OS X 10.11.
However, I must build using older Xcode SDK (10.8) to support older platform.
I have a problem when I link to libpng installed using homebrew.
A bunch of warnings like following pop up:

> Object file
>   (/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.21/lib/libpng.16.a(pngwutil.o)) was
>   built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.8)

The problem would be obviously solved if I could force homebrew to compile recipe using older Xcode SDK (10.8) but haven't find a way to accomplish this.

Any suggestion is welcome.